# how to make order by for union query in DB 2

Tags: sql, db2

i have  a problem  how to order by in DB2 Anyone have any idea?.

**select col1,col2 from a 
union select col1,col2 from b**

```
BEFORE
----Result----
col1    col2
a       abu
b       bala
d       daus
f       faiz
h       haikal
c       canon
e       elly
g       gous

AFTER
----Result----
col1    col2
a       abu
b       bala
c       canon
d       daus
e       elly
f       faiz
g       gous
h       haikal
```

Comment: Add `ORDER BY col1` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Jarlh's comment is correct...

```
select col1,col2 
from a 
union 
select col1,col2 from b
ORDER BY col1,col2
```

Only a single `ORDER BY` is allowed as it applies to the entire result set.

Answer (score 0):

specify column name to order simply

```
select col1,col2 
from a 
union 
select col1,col2 from b
ORDER BY col1,col2
```

or specify rank column to order

```
select col1,col2 
from a 
union 
select col1,col2 from b
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

Note: if col1 has unique value (by exemple if col1 is a key column), your should use union all and not union. "Union" remove doublons then "union all" is better for performance

```
select col1,col2 
from a 
union all
select col1,col2 from b
ORDER BY col1,col2
```

Answer (score -1):

Using subquery you can do this:

select * from (
select col1,col2 from a union select col1,col2 from b
) table1
order by table1.col1